# Dietary requirements in CIVI event

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

I'm looking for the dietary requirements in Civi Event an I can't locate the option. Please could you help?

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 3):

You would have to add a custom field. You could add the custom field at the level of participant, where you would save the dietary requirement for that specific person at that specific event.

Alternative is to keep it at Individual level where you would record the dietary requirements of the person at any event.

Do you know how to create custom fields in CiviCRM?

Comment: You can access custom fields in yoursite.com/civicrm/admin/custom/group?reset=1

Check if there are any participant custom field groups or individual field groups as ErikH has suggested

Comment: For sure store data at the Participant level! Gluten free is in right now - but mat not last

Answer (score 1):

That's not something built-in.  However, it's quite easy to add using custom fields.